# Find equivalent results under distributive and commutative laws

Tags: python, operators

I have a script that loops over 5 vectors of numbers and mix them with all the four operations searching for a combination that give a certain target number as a result.

The script prints an output like:

```
312 / 130 x 350 - 122 + 282 = 1000.0
312 / 130 x 350 + 282 - 122 = 1000.0
312 - 282 x 372 / 15 + 256 = 1000.0
142 + 350 - 372 x 125 / 15 = 1000.0
142 + 350 - 372 / 15 x 125 = 1000.0
350 / 130 x 312 + 282 - 122 = 1000.0
350 + 142 - 372 x 125 / 15 = 1000.0
```

Each line is formatted from a list of the numbers and a list of the operations.

What I'd like to do, is to **remove the equivalent results**, i.e. having an output like:

```
312 / 130 x 350 - 122 + 282 = 1000.0
312 - 282 x 372 / 15 + 256 = 1000.0
142 + 350 - 372 x 125 / 15 = 1000.0
```

As a solution, at first, I thought about "remembering" the numbers that already gave 1000 and skip those, but then I realized it might shadow new results, so I don't know what to do.

How can I find the equivalent results under distributive and commutative laws?

**Note:** In the presented output the parentheses are NOT shown, but the order is reduce-like, meaning that, for example:

```
142 + 350 - 372 x 125 / 15 = 1000.0
```

is calculated like:

```
(((142 + 350) - 372) x 125) / 15 = 1000.0
```

---

This is the code I have so far:

```
import operator
from itertools import permutations, product, count
from functools import reduce

vectors = [[87, 125, 209, 312],
           [29, 122, 254, 372],
           [15, 130, 277, 369],
           [142, 197, 282, 383],
           [64, 157, 256, 350]]

OPER = {operator.add: '+', operator.sub: '-', operator.mul: 'x', 
        operator.truediv: '/'}

def format_result(nums, ops, res):
    s = ' '.join('{} {}'.format(n,OPER[op]) for n,op in zip(nums, ops))
    s += ' {} = {}'.format(nums[-1], res)
    return s

def calc(vectors, test=lambda x: x == 1000.):
    for vv in permutations(vectors):
        for indexes in product((0,1,2,3), repeat=5):
            numbers = tuple(v[i] for i,v in zip(indexes, vv))
            for operations in permutations(OPER):
                res = reduce(lambda x,y,n=count(0): operations[next(n)](x,y),
                             numbers)
                if test(res):
                    print(format_result(numbers, operations, res))

calc(vectors)
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but you should probably avoid using floats and exact comparisons.  This code will report "350 / 130 x 312 + 282 - 122" but not "350 / 130 x 312 - 122 + 282" because of a 1.13686837722e-13 discrepancy.  You can use fractions.Fraction instead (at a significant speed penalty, I admit).  For the problem itself, I think I'd go the other way: first generate all the distinct under dist. and comm. five-term operation patterns, and then plug the numbers in.

Comment: Very interesting question indeed.

Comment: @DSM: Since most of the time I check for what combination goes most near to the target I didn't worry too much now, but I'll sure keep it in mind for the next step. About the other way around: I didn't thought of that! It'll be easier than to compare numbers and operations toghter, but I'd still have to know how to generate all the equivalent patterns?

Comment: @Rik: Can you give an example of different solutions that can be derived from each other using distributivity? I actually doubt that this is an issue because of the order of operator application and the fixed number of operands (but I'm not sure).

Comment: @Nik: Alas I can't, mine was just a fear. In an a "non reduce-like" situation the order should be an issue (I'd have to thought of an example, but I'm pretty sure). So I inferred it may be here too, maybe less likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem can be approached by grouping the operands according to the operations performed on them. Example:

```
312 / 130 x 350 + 122 + 282   => (/, [312, 130]), (x, [350]), (+, [122, 282])
```

You can then place certain constraints on the order of these groups:

1. `-` groups cannot occur directly before `+` groups
2. `/` groups cannot occur directly before `*` groups
3. within each group, the order of the numbers must be ascending

Possible groupings would thus look like this:

- "first 3 asc. operands connected with a `+`, then 2 asc. operands connected with a `*`"
- "first 1 asc. operand connected with a `+`, then 2 asc. operands connected with a `*`, then 2 asc. operands connected with `/`"

Impossible would be something like this:

- "first 2 asc. operands connected with a `-`, then 3 asc. operands connected with `+`" (would collide with "first 3 asc. operands connected with a `+`, then 2 asc. operands connected with `-`

I tried a brute-force approach to create and fill such groupings, but it's unbearably slow. Maybe you can optimize it to be more efficient :) Could also be that there's some subtle bug in there, but unfortunately I don't have any more time to work on it:

```
import operator
import fractions
from itertools import permutations, product, count
from functools import reduce

vectors = [[87, 125, 209, 312],
           [29, 122, 254, 372],
           [15, 130, 277, 369],
           [142, 197, 282, 383],
           [64, 157, 256, 350]]
vectors = [[fractions.Fraction(x) for x in v] for v in vectors]

operators = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.div,
    }

def create_groupings(n, exclude = ()):
  if n <= 0: yield ()
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    if not '+' in exclude:
      for rest in create_groupings(n - i, ('+',)):
        yield ((i, '+'),) + rest
    if not '-' in exclude:
      for rest in create_groupings(n - i, ('+', '-')):
        yield ((i, '-'),) + rest
    if not '*' in exclude:
      for rest in create_groupings(n - i, ('*',)):
        yield ((i, '*'),) + rest
    if not '/' in exclude:
      for rest in create_groupings(n - i, ('/', '*')):
        yield ((i, '/'),) + rest

def fill_grouping(groups, vectors):
  if len(groups) == 0:
    yield ()
    return

  (group_size, op), grest = groups[0], groups[1:]
  for vv in permutations(vectors):
    vecs, vrest = vectors[:group_size], vectors[group_size:]
    for operands in map(list, product(*vecs)):
      # enforce ascending ordering to avoid collisions
      # like A + B == B + A
      if operands != sorted(operands): continue
      for rest in fill_grouping(grest, vrest):
        yield ((op, operands),) + rest

groupings = create_groupings(5)
for g in groupings:
  for groups in fill_grouping(g, vectors):
    evaluated = ((op, reduce(operators[op], x)) for (op, x) in groups)
    _, value = reduce(lambda (_, x), (op, y): (None, operators[op](x,y)), evaluated)
    if 1000 == value:
      print groups
```

Hope this helps (at least the idea :)

Comment: For a saturday night is great :) I'll take a look at it!